# How to pass data between controllers with a service in Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am trying to pass data between controllers with a service but I am having trouble as it returns nothing.

Here is my service:

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    var savedData = "";
    return {
        get: function () {
            //You could also return specific attribute of the form data instead
            //of the entire data
            return savedData;
        },
        set: function (data) {
            //You could also set specific attribute of the form data instead
            this.savedData = data;
        }
    };

});
```

Here is the controller saving the data using a function called goToAccount():

```
app.controller("chatController", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray", "Auth", "$window", "$state", "myService",
    function($scope, $firebaseArray, Auth, $window, $state, myService) {
        $scope.message = 'ChatRoom';
        $scope.auth = Auth;
        $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
        $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
        console.log("Name: "+firebaseUser.displayName + "," + firebaseUser.email);
        firebaseUser.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
            console.log("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
            console.log("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
            console.log("  Provider Name: "+profile.displayName);
            console.log("  Provider Email: "+profile.email);
            console.log("  Provider Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);
            user = profile;
          });

        });

        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");
        // create a synchronized array
        $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);
        // add new items to the array
        // the message is automatically added to our Firebase database!
        $scope.addMessage = function() {
            $scope.messages.$add({
              user: user.displayName,
              email: user.email,
              text: $scope.newMessageText
            });
        };
        $scope.goToAccount = function(email){
            myService.set(email);
            console.log(" Email: "+email);
            $window.location.href = "/account.html"
        }
    }
]);
```

And here is the controller that is getting the data. myService.get() returns empty space:

```
app.controller("accountCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$window", "$state",     "$stateParams", "myService",
    function($scope, Auth, $window, $state, $stateParams, myService) {  
        console.log(myService.get());
        $scope.message = 'Account Page for id' + myService.get();
    }
]);
```

The function goToAccount is triggered in html with a ng-click:

```
<a ng-click="goToAccount(message.email)">
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to pass data between controllers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are setting `this.savedData` which is the context of your service, in other words setting a property of your service. However your returning `savedData` which is just a normal variable not part of your service. Either use `this` on both the get and set or omit it for both. Don't mix and match. You are looking at two different `savedData`'s if that makes sense.

Comment: If i do return this.savedData it returns undefined?

Comment: `this.savedData = data` this refers to the context where you calling the service.
 Just use `savedData = data`

Comment: btw i am just curious, how is your $route configured? are u using push state feature of html5? i saw that u are probably using `angular-ui-router` but u are changing the states by setting $window.location.href?

Comment: @CarpoolTunnel it will do if you try to get before it has been set. However if your going to use `this` you may as well just access the property directly with `myService.savedData` if you want getters and setter i presume you want the actual data private to the service in which case omit the `this` for both. [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/n9cg1emm/3/) a working fiddle using `this` for reference.

Comment: Hmm, I tried with what was in your fiddle and it seems that the set isnt working since it returns 'some default value'. @MMhunter I haven't done anything with route yet. Still trying to figure that out.

Comment: @CarpoolTunnel His fiddle should work if u implement your controller and $route configuration right.  I am doubting that your way of changing states by setting `$window.location.href` will cause the page redirection (like a page refreshing) ,other than a hash change (the real angular way to handle route change), and then all your angular modules are initialised again. This could make the service always keep default value since you are recreating it every time route changes.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of sharing data between controller or components whatsoever.

Some of them are using services, $rootScope, events, local storage

I'll give a few examples

Sharing data with:
 **$rootScope**

```
module.controller('Controller5a',function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.shared='hello';
  $scope.$watch('shared',function(newValue){
    $rootScope.shared=$scope.shared
    })
});

module.controller('Controller5b', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.shared=''
  $rootScope.$watch('shared',function(newValue){
  $scope.shared=$rootScope.shared;
})
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adutu/rs4tg6qx/41/

This is not recommended because you are polluting the $rootScope

Sharing data with:
**Service**

because services and factories are singletons then you can do this

```
module.service('Share', function(){

    return { text: 'hello' };
});

module.controller('Controller5a',function($scope, Share) {
  $scope.Share = Share

});

module.controller('Controller5b', function($scope, Share) {
    $scope.Share = Share

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adutu/rs4tg6qx/55/ with factory
http://jsfiddle.net/adutu/osd0sm9q/ with service

if you want to use service instead of factory in this example just change the factory to service and you are done :)

or this with set and get

```
module.factory('Share', function(){
   var text ='hello';
   return { 
     get: function(){
       return text;
    },
     set: function(value){
      text=value;
      console.log(text);
    },
      value:text
    };
});

module.controller('Controller5a',function($scope, Share) {
  $scope.text = Share.get();
  $scope.set = function(){
    Share.set($scope.text);
  }
});

module.controller('Controller5b', function($scope, Share) {
    $scope.Share = Share;//to bind
    //use $scope.text = Share.get() //not to bind
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adutu/s9obvz57/1/

Sharing data with:
With **events**

```
module.controller('Controller5a',function($scope) {
  $scope.text='hello';
  $scope.$watch('text',function(newValue,oldValue){
    //console.log(newValue);
    //this with send the message to $rootScope
    $scope.$emit('share',$scope.text);
  })
});

module.controller('Controller5b', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('share', function(event,response){
    console.log(response);
    $scope.text = response;
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adutu/6bo1ojn1/11/

Comment: Some good examples and info, however there's one issue. Your binding directly your service to your `$scope`. This should be avoided, any changes you make to that object add/delete properties for example will be propagated to all other entities using that service which is obviously not good. It also helps to keep that separation. In your example you mention service but use a factory. Not trying to bring it down, just mentioning for anyone new to angular.

Comment: @ste2425 you are right it should be avoided if don't want the automatic binding. It's just many times you want it so it's the easiest way. Factory and service do the same thing except the way are instantiated by angular so it can be safe to assume that both are used as services. You can read more here if you are interested http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Comment: @ste2425 I've edited the service example a little bit so it's not confusing for the beginners :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I found that $window.location.href was causing the service to reset so I implemented state changes and now the service saves.

Answer (score 1):

So your running into a scoping vs context issue. Ill try to explain

The setter

```
set: function(data) {
     this.savedData = data;
},
```

Is looking at your services context, or your service it self for the property `savedData`. If using `this` inside your service methods it will expose that property on your service itself. So you could access it in your controller with `myService.savedData` or even set it there for that matter.

The getter:

```
  get: function() {
    return savedData;
  }
```

Is just referencing a normal variable, not too sure off the top of my head if its closures or lexical scoping (leaning towards lexcial) that makes this work. Any way JavaScript will first look in the `set` method for `savedData` if it can't find it it will work its way back up to the service declaration where you initially set  `var savedData = "";` and use that variable instead.

So as you can see your service is using two different `savedData`'s for each method.

You should either use `this` for both, exposing the underlying data property of your service. If that's acceptable you may as well loose the getter's and setters and just access the property directly.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/n9cg1emm/6/)

Or omit the `this` and have `savedData` private to your service and only have it accessible inside your service.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/n9cg1emm/7/)

---

EDIT

This is for the underlying issue with your service, however i think @MMhunter may be onto to something with his comment. You say when you implement the services correctly it still doesn't work. Yet your redirecting to another page after setting the service value. If you are not maintianing your app state on that page reload then your angular app will 'reboot' on the new page load loosing all data set in the service. Single page apps that work like this don't reload the entire page, they use partials and the url hash to load a new partial, this means the entire page doesn't reload and so your app doesn't reload loosing state. There is an alternative to making your app maintain its state between page loads and that's using `local/sessionStorage`. Don't know the design of the rest of your app so may not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Your service have a typo

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    var savedData = '';
    return {
        get: function () {
            //You could also return specific attribute of the form data instead
            //of the entire data
            return savedData;
        },
        set: function (data) {
            //You could also set specific attribute of the form data instead
            savedData = data;
        }
    };

});
```

You are setting value in `this.savedData` but you declared it as `var` and you are returning savedData which is `""`.

Comment: I think your getting mixed up with context's of services. This currently throws an undefined exception on `savedData`. [see](https://jsfiddle.net/n9cg1emm/1/). The context of your `.service` is different to the context of the returned object. Just FYI it is not always better to use a factory, they are two different things for two different use cases. Services are singletons, their 'instance' will be shared across your app. Factories are not.

Comment: Can you explain why the fiddle with your service isn't working then? Am i implementing it wrong?

Comment: Ok got it, see now

Answer (score 0):

if you are using service services then it always return only array.

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    var savedData = [];

        this.getsavedData = function () {
            //You could also return specific attribute of the form data instead
            //of the entire data
            return savedData;
        }
        this.setsavedData = function (data) {
            //You could also set specific attribute of the form data instead
            savedData = data;
        }


});
```

to know and learn about services look this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUXku28ex-M)

Inside your **chatController**

do this to check it is working or not like that

`myService.setsavedData("welcome");`

inside your **accountCtrl**

here try to return the value welcome in alert

`alert(myService.getsavedData());`

Comment: It returns an empty array then.

Comment: NO you see in the **function(data)** you pass paramenter like this `myService.setsavedData("hello")` in one ctrl and try to call `myService.getsavedData()` in another ctrl it will work

Comment: inside your setsaveData update my answer please look it

Comment: Its returning undefined now. I have:

 app.service('myService', function() {
  var savedData = [];

   this.get = function () {
    //You could also return specific attribute of the form data instead
    //of the entire data
    savedData;
   }
   this.set = function (data) {
    //You could also set specific attribute of the form data instead
    savedData = data;
   }


 });

Comment: what you have tried show me so that i can see if there is any issue

Comment: this.set = function (data) this line wrong change with my answer

Comment: app.service('myService', function() {
  var savedData = [];

   this.get = function () {
    savedData;
   }
   this.set = function (data) {
    savedData = data;
   }


 });

Comment: use as i used in my answer this.getsavedData = function(){ return savedData);

Comment: I have what you have above:
app.service('myService', function() {
    var savedData = [];

        this.getsavedData = function () {
            //You could also return specific attribute of the form data instead
            //of the entire data
            return savedData;
        }
        this.setsavedData = function (data) {
            //You could also set specific attribute of the form data instead
            savedData = data;
        }


});

with myService.setsavedData("" + email); and $scope.message = 'Account Page for id' + myService.getsavedData(); but its empty

Comment: and dont forget to inject myService inside your controller

Comment: It is still empty space

Comment: then you have problem with your login check your controller part or send me  your two controller part show me how you have implemented it